# Weird behavior of indexes when iterating through a 2D array

Tags: c, arrays

I have a typedef'ed struct:

```
typedef struct {
    int x, y;
}TPosition;
```

and a function that returns the *position* of the very first element in the array that is non-negative:

```
TPosition startPos(int **arr, int lin, int col) {
TPosition p;

int i, j;
for(i = 0; i < lin; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < col; j++) {
        if(nonNeg(arr[i][j])) {
            p.x = i;
            p.y = j;
            break;
        }
    }
    break;
}

return p;
}
```

In `main` I have: `pos = startPos(arr, lin, col);`, where `pos` is `TPosition pos;`

Everything works well when there are non-negative integers in the first row. If `arr` is an array such that:
-1 -1
 2  1
then the output is not correct. The debugger shows that the index j goes over the bound (j = col).

This is rather weird, though it is extremely simple.
Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the outer break doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should initialize `p` to something, so that you can find out if none is found.

the `break;`s are false. Replace the first one with `return p;` and remove the second one, otherwise the outer for loop will not do anything after the first iteration.

```
TPosition startPos(int **arr, int lin, int col) {
TPosition p = { -1, -1};

int i, j;
for(i = 0; i < lin; i++) {
    for(j = 0; j < col; j++) {
        if(nonNeg(arr[i][j])) {
            p.x = i;
            p.y = j;
            return p;
        }
    }
}
return p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the inner `break;` to `return p;` and this kind of thing is why I avoid `break;`, also note that if no position is found, you would return `p` unintialized, I can't tell you how to initialize it, but I can suggest you choose some invalid value, and use that.

Comment: I really think whoever downvoted this answer is a ... because it was posted before the other correct answer, as was my comment to the question which if I include here, this answer will be as complete as the other one, I don't really care about `-2` reputation, But I worry about this kind of users...